# VIsiting Jordan as an unmarried couple

Tags: hotels, jordan

I have been planning to visit Jordan (Amman or Aqaba, itinerary not fully scheduled yet) with my girlfriend. To my great surprise some of the hotels I looked through hotel consolidator websites claim that two persons of separate sex require a marriage certificate in order to share a room.

Does this rule really apply to foreigner and/or non-Muslim visitors as well? (We are both Finnish citizens, if that matters.)

Comment: Middle east is pretty conservative when it comes to inter-sex relationships, and they can get pretty aggressive if offended. Be respectful, you're a guest in their country.

Comment: While the Middle East is indeed more conservative, most countries have a "don't ask, don't tell" attitude where it comes to these matters. The only country that really makes an issue of this is Iran afaik.

Answer (score 3):

https://www.gov.uk/foreign-travel-advice/jordan/local-laws-and-customs

> Although co-habitation for unmarried foreign couples of the opposite sex isn’t illegal, it may be frowned upon. Some landlords may even ask if you are married or ask for a marriage certificate.

*May* is the key word here. And also landlords: you might have more problems in an airbnb than a hotel.

People from Jordan

https://www.reddit.com/r/jordan/comments/qrgg3q/travel_in_jordan_as_an_unmarried_couple/

and people who have travelled to Jordan

https://www.reddit.com/r/travel/comments/elol54/travel_in_jordan_as_an_unmarried_straight_couple/

both agree as a foreigner you will have no problems. There seems to be different rules for Jordanians.

Comment: For those few places that might want a marriage certificate - I wonder if they know what a Finnish Marriage Certificate looks like?